# Multi cluster CockroachDB with Cilium Cluster Mesh

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, cockroachdb, cilium

I am trying to enable a multi cluster CockroachDB spawning 3 k8s clusters connected with Cilium Cluster Mesh. The idea of having a multi cluster CockroachDB is described on [cockroachlabs.com - 1](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/cockroachdb-kubernetes-cilium/), [2](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/orchestrate-cockroachdb-with-kubernetes-multi-cluster). Given the fact that the article calls for a [change in CoreDNS ConfigMap](https://github.com/cockroachlabs-field/cockroachdb-multiregion-k3s-ciliumcni-azure/blob/master/example-configmap-eastus.yaml), instead of using Cilium [global-services](https://docs.cilium.io/en/latest/network/clustermesh/services/#load-balancing-service-discovery) feels suboptimal.

Therefore the question arises, how to enable a multi cluster CockroachDB in a Cilium Cluster Mesh environment, using Cilium global services instead of hacking CoreDNS ConfigMap ?

With CockroachDB installed via helm, it deploys a [StatefulSet](https://github.com/cockroachdb/helm-charts/blob/master/cockroachdb/templates/statefulset.yaml#L171) with a carefully crafted `--join` parameter. It contains FQDNs of CockroachDB pods that are to join the cluster.

The pod FQDNs come from [service.discover](https://github.com/cockroachdb/helm-charts/blob/master/cockroachdb/templates/service.discovery.yaml) that is created with `clusterIP: None` and

> (...) only exists to create DNS entries for each pod in the StatefulSet such that they can resolve each other's IP addresses.

The discovery service automatically registers DNS entries for all pods within the StatefulSet, so that they can be [easily referenced](https://github.com/cockroachdb/helm-charts/blob/master/cockroachdb/templates/statefulset.yaml#L177)

Can a similar *discovery service* or alternative be created for a StatefulSet running on a *remote* cluster ? So that with cluster mesh enabled, pods J,K,L in cluster Β could be reached from pods X,Y,Z in cluster Α by their FQDN ?

As suggested in [create-service-per-pod-in-statefulset](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/11997/create-service-per-pod-in-statefulset), one could create services like

```
{{- range $i, $_ := until 3 -}}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerate-unready-endpoints: "true"
    io.cilium/global-service: 'true'
    service.cilium.io/affinity: "remote"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: cockroachdb
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: dbs
    app.kubernetes.io/name: cockroachdb
  name: dbs-cockroachdb-remote-{{ $i }}
  namespace: dbs
spec:
  ports:
  - name: grpc
    port: 26257
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: grpc
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: cockroachdb
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: dbs
    app.kubernetes.io/name: cockroachdb
    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: cockroachdb-{{ $i }}
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  publishNotReadyAddresses: true
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dbs-cockroachdb-public-remote-{{ $i }}
  namespace: dbs
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: cockroachdb
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: dbs
    app.kubernetes.io/name: cockroachdb
  annotations:
    io.cilium/global-service: 'true'
    service.cilium.io/affinity: "remote"
spec:
  ports:
  - name: grpc
    port: 26257
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: grpc
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: cockroachdb
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: dbs
    app.kubernetes.io/name: cockroachdb
{{- end -}}
```

So that they resemble the original [service.discovery](https://github.com/cockroachdb/helm-charts/blob/master/cockroachdb/templates/service.discovery.yaml) and [service.public](https://github.com/cockroachdb/helm-charts/blob/master/cockroachdb/templates/service.public.yaml)

However, despite the presence of cilium annotations

```
io.cilium/global-service: 'true'
service.cilium.io/affinity: "remote"
```

services look bound to the *local* k8s cluster, resulting in CockroachDB consisting of 3 instead of 6 nodes. (3 in cluster A + 3 in cluster B)

**hubble**:
[image: no cross connect]
**CockroachDB**:
[image: CockroachDB dash]

It does not matter how which service (`dbs-cockroachdb-public-remote-X`, or `dbs-cockroachdb-remote-X`) I use in my [`--join` command overwrite](https://github.com/cockroachdb/helm-charts/blob/master/cockroachdb/values.yaml#L61)

```
    join:
      - dbs-cockroachdb-0.dbs-cockroachdb.dbs:26257
      - dbs-cockroachdb-1.dbs-cockroachdb.dbs:26257
      - dbs-cockroachdb-2.dbs-cockroachdb.dbs:26257
      - dbs-cockroachdb-public-remote-0.dbs:26257
      - dbs-cockroachdb-public-remote-1.dbs:26257
      - dbs-cockroachdb-public-remote-2.dbs:26257
```

The result is the same, 3 nodes instead of 6.

Any ideas?

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: You should not use `io.cilium/global-service: 'true'` in the first place. Since the moment you will add a third cluster, which remote will it point to? Can be any of the 2. You don't want this. At this moment Cilium ClusterMesh seems a bit underdeveloped for this use-case. Ultimately you would just want to expose unique services across clusters, like `cockroachdb-0.eu-west.svc.cluster.local` and `cockroachdb-0.us-east.svc.cluster.local`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently due to [7070](https://github.com/cilium/cilium/issues/7070), patching CoreDNS ConfigMap is the most reasonable thing we can do. In the comments of that bug, an [article is mentioned](https://faun.pub/connecting-multiple-kubernetes-clusters-on-vsphere-with-the-cilium-cluster-mesh-964f95267df4), that provides additional context.

My twist to this story is that I updated the config map with kubernetes plugin config:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |-
    saturn.local {
      log
      errors
      kubernetes saturn.local {
        endpoint https://[ENDPOINT]
        kubeconfig [PATH_TO_KUBECONFIG]
      }
    }
    rhea.local {
      ...
```

So that I could resolve other names as well.
In my setup, each cluster has its own `domain.local`. `PATH_TO_KUBECONFIG` is a plane kubeconfig file. Generic secret has to be created in `kube-system` namespace and the secret volume has to be mounted under coredns deployment.

[image: it works]

Comment: I indeed think this is the best way as of now. Another solution that should be maybe even nicer, is if Cilium ClusterMesh could  connect to the ClusterIP of the CoreDNS service on the other cluster. That way, yuou don't need the kubernetes plugin in CoreDNS anymore and you can just `forward . ` to the CoreDNS ClusterIP.

Sadly, as of now, I don't know of a good way to let Cilium ClusterMesh connect to the services CIDR range.